# What's the file path of context.openFileOutput()

Tags: java, android, serialization, storage

I want to know the actual path my files are being written to (in the storage) using `context.openFileOutput()` as shown below (skipped the exceptions).

```
public static void writeObject(Context context, String name, Object object){

    FileOutputStream fos = context.openFileOutput(name, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
    oos.writeObject(object);
    oos.close();
    fos.close();

   }
```

Comment: The number of serialized objects is 1. Are you asking how many *files* there are?

Comment: You are only saving one serialozed object per file. Either the answer is 1 or you want to know how many files there are. Make up your mind. Your comment on @Commonsware's answer agrees with me.

Comment: NB The edit you rolled back was correct. [tag:android-studio] doesn't have anything to do with this. You're not asking how to work the IDE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can I get the exact path

You are using `openFileInput()` and `openFileOutput()`. Those files are stored in the the location identified by `getFilesDir()`.

> also the total number of objects saved in that path/directory?

Well, it seems like you are only storing one object per file. You can use `listFiles()` on the `File` object returned by `getFilesDir()` to see what files are in that directory. You would then need to identify which of those files represent your objects (versus other files that wound up in that directory), and count those.

Answer (score 1):

First, I want you to understand some things:

[getFilesDir()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getFilesDir()) returns a file object from which you can get a path/location.

Calling `getFilesDir().listFiles()` returns an array of all the files you've saved with `openFileInput()` and `openFileInput()`.

From the explanation above, your files are all located in the `getFilesDir()` path.

Comment: I had this problem about two years ago but thanks! I hope this helps someone else.